# Return text of element on the page

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, gettext

How do I make the method return the text value of an element on the page, using Selenium with JS? Now returns undefined

homepage.js

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
let Basepage = require('../pageobjects/basepage');
    
class Homepage extends Basepage {
    
 isAviasales(){
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@class='header__title']")).getText().then(function(txt){
             return txt+'';});
        }
module.exports = new Homepage();
```

basepage.js

```
    let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 10000 } );

class Basepage{
    constructor(){
        global.driver = driver;
    }

   go_to_url(theURL){
       return driver.get(theURL);      
    }
}

module.exports = Basepage;
```

testpage.js

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const homepage = require('../pageobjects/homepage');
let baseurl = 'https://www.aviasales.by/';

describe('Tests are starting', function(){
      this.timeout(7000);
   
    it('Mainpage test',function(){
        
        homepage.go_to_url(baseurl);
     // assert.equal(homepage.isAviasales(),'Поиск дешёвых авиабилетов');
    })

    it('Omsk test',function(){                     
        homepage.enterText('Омск');
      //  assert.equal(homepage.isOMS(),'OMS');
    })

    it('Swap test',function(){                
       homepage.clickSwapPlaces();
    })
})
```

MoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetailsMoredetails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am testing website with mocha and js.  assert.equal(homepage.isAviasales(),'Поиск дешёвых авиабилетов'); - AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Поиск дешёвых авиабилетов'. I need my test to work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a `wait` here.
I guess the element you are trying to access is still not completely loaded on the web page when you trying to access it and retrieve it's text content.
To give better answer we need to see all your code here.

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: I see, thanks. I don't know JS, but I cant see here where / how you waiting for `header__title` element to be completely loaded before extracting it text content.

Comment: I don't know js either :) Only Java :) I don't quite understand how to apply waits correctly here

Comment: Me too :) I use Java, also know Python and somewhat C#. JS is different